# Is this diagram possible or correct?

Tags: database-design

just starting to learn to design. I don't know the term in english to describe this type of design, so I'm here for some help.

Can this "specialitzations" have a relation like this one? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Where is this "specializations"? I can't see it.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how it is in english.

Products is divided into natural and artificial.

Comment: Ah ok then. And the question is about the "created by" relationship?

Comment: Exactly, sorry!

Comment: Yes, every relation can be related to any other one (or even to itself.) I can't get my head to figure how an ArtificialProduct would be "created by" a NaturalProduct or vice versa but yes, it is allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is allowed. Every relation can be related to any other one (or even to itself.)

The naming does not help much but if the `created by` means the (`natural`) "ingredients" that an `artificial product` is composed of, then it makes sense to use a many-to-many relationship.